# Read Specific Bytes Out of Byte Array C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I am a newbie with a question regarding reading specific bytes out of an array in C#. I received an array response that is 128 bytes long and I am looking to read and store the first 4 bytes of the array. How do I do so?

I've read a number of posts about shifting bytes but was a bit confused and I am looking to get going in the right direction.

Comment: What data type do you expect the bytes to represent? i.e. do you just want to process them as individual bytes, or are the first 4 bytes actually an integer?

Comment: Agreed, this is surely an XY question.

Comment: I want to process them as bytes and store them in an array so that it reads { 1,2,3,4}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use one of the [`Array.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overloads:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[4];

Array.Copy(originalArray, bytes, bytes.Length);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Array.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
// your original array
var sourceArray = new byte[128];

// create a new one with the size you need
var firstBytes = new byte[4];

// copy the required number of bytes.
Array.Copy(sourceArray, 0, firstBytes, 0, firstBytes.Length);
```

If you do not need the rest of the data in the original array, you can also resize it, truncating everything after the first 4 bytes:

```
Array.Resize(ref sourceArray, 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the first 4 bytes in 4 different variables:

```
byte first = array[0],
    second = array[1],
    third = array[2],
    forth = array[4];
```

Read them as one 32-bit long integer:

```
int result = 
    first << 24 ||
    second << 16 ||
    third << 8 ||
    forth;
```

The `x << n` operator shifts the bits of number `x`, `n` times to the left. You are effectively moving the bytes of `first` 24 positions to the left, thus `first` will be stored in bits with indices 24 to 31 like that:

```
first 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

Next, move `second` 16 positions to the left, thus storing it in bits 16 to 23 and so on:

```
first second 00000000 00000000
```

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) provides a good summary of bitwise operations if you need more details.

Comment: BitConverter makes it possible to avoid the bit shifting.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384066.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.  Although, this is only available if you are using .NET 3.5 or later.  You will need to have `using System.Linq;` at the top of the .cs file.

```
var bytes = originalArray.Take(4).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Example from a network stream.

```
byte[] bytesRead = 0;
using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
{
    byte[] length = new byte[4];
    bytesRead = stream.Read(length, 0, 4);
}
```

bytesRead contains the first 4 bytes stored in the networkstream.